# Verify that the identity $Log(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) = Log(1+z) - Log(1-z)$ holds when $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Verify that the identity

$$Log(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) = Log(1+z) - Log(1-z)$$ holds when $|z|<1$.

The procedure on the book is as follows:

\begin{align*}
  Log(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) &= Log|\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}|+iArg(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) \\
 &= Log|1+z|-iLog|1-z| +iArg(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) \\
\end{align*}

Now $|z|<1$ insures that $1+$ and $1-z$ lie in the right half plane so this equals
\begin{align*}
&=Log|1+z| -Log|1-z| +iArg(1+z)-iArg(1-z)\\
&=Log(1+z) - Log(1-z)
\end{align*}

---

I don't really understand how did they go from first line to second line[ ie .$Log|1+z|-iLog|1-z| +iArg(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z})$]. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: If there's really an $i$ in the book before the $\operatorname{Log} \lvert 1-z\rvert$, that's a typo or error. Otherwise, for real $a,b> 0$, you know $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b$, don't you?

Comment: @DanielFischer, the book does have $iLog|1-z|$, so it must be a typo. And I'm also not sure about the derivation of third line, why $iArg(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}) = iArg(1+z) - iArg(1-z)$?

Comment: You always have $\operatorname{Arg} \frac{a}{b} \equiv \operatorname{Arg} a - \operatorname{Arg} b \pmod{2\pi}$. Here, $1\pm z$ is in the right half-plane, so the arguments (principal branch) lie between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, thus their difference lies between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, hence is the principal branch of the argument of the quotient.